# Loop through array to append circles using d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an array consisting of multiple pairs of lat/lon coordinates that I would like to loop through, using d3 to append circle to the map for each coordinate pair in the array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var aa = [[-122.490402, 37.786453],[-149.882154, 61.138793]];
console.log(aa[0]);
console.log(aa[1]);

var breweryCircles = [];
for (i=0;i<=aa.length;i++) {
    breweryCircles.push(aa[i]);


    g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(breweryCircles)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(breweryCircles)[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(breweryCircles)[1]; })
        .attr("r", "2px")
        .attr("fill", "red")            
};
```

One circle will draw, but I get an error message in the console for the second circle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, when you write a D3 code, you normally **don't need** any kind of loop. Of course, we use loops sometimes, but in very specific situations and to solve very specific problems.

That being said, simply **bind** the data to create your circles in the enter selection. This is the "D3 way", which will append as many circles as the length of your data array:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(aa)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
```

And that's all you need. Drop that `for` loop, which is not only unnecessary but also will hinder your D3 learning process.

Here is a demo (the data array has no geographic coordinates, just the SVG coordinates, but the principle is the same):

```js
var aa = [[20, 37],[40, 61],[203, 77], [143, 107]];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(aa)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    
circles.attr("cx", d=>d[0])
    .attr("cy", d=>d[1])
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "teal")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

**PS**: Your code, although not the best D3 practice, **is** working. The error you're getting is simply due to the fact that you're using `<=` in the `for` loop, when you should use just `<`. Have a look at your code with that change:

```js
var aa = [[20, 37],[40, 61],[203, 77], [143, 107]];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var breweryCircles = [];
for (i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
//use < here--^
    breweryCircles.push(aa[i]);

    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(breweryCircles)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d[1];
        })
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "red")
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```